# Is is possible to have a ghost mode that is also tachyonic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

(The concepts involved in this question might be way beyond my undergrad level, but curiosity caused me to ask about it. The answers left behind for this question, however might be useful for me (when I finally learnt the prerequisites) and other interested readers in the future)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WASay.png (Screencap used instead because most people cannot access the site)
[image]

From this site, I am briefly introduced the meaning of ghost modes (wrong sign in the kinetic term of the Lagrangian), and some time ago, I read about that tachyons are instabilities in the potential of a theory (Wrong sign in the potential term of the Lagrangian)

> Therefore I was wondering, **what if both the kinetic and potential term of the Lagrangian gone wrong at the same time**, do we end up with a ghost tachyon mode or we are still ok because of how the Lagrangian has only kinetic and potential terms, thus both going wrong at the same time is the same as inverting the sign of the Lagrangian?
>
> If we end up with a ghost tachyon mode, what are the possible physical interpretations of it, besides implying an instability in both the momentum and potential?

Comment: I tried to go to the site about the ghost, and it stuck my computer.

Comment: http://relativity.livingreviews.org

.The way I visited that page is I first go here, and then type "Ghost" in the google search box to the right of the page, and then click the item from the result of that search

.For me, that link has to be left clicked to visit, opening it in a new window or tab also lead to 502 bad gateway for some reason

.I hope my screencap of it is large enough to read, which I included in case the website cannot be visited by other conputers for technical reasons

Comment: If that's still too small to read, I will fix it by using imgur to host it instead

Comment: Could you not put directly the address of the article? It's not a pleasure to begin a *go here, go there, etc.* I saw no "For me".

Comment: I have included an imgur screencap of the web's content, which luckily fits in one page. You can browse that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have ghost tachyons. A ghost tachyon would be a particle of negative mass-squared (tachyon) which possesses negative energy (ghost).

Such a (quantum) theory would be unstable, as pointed out in your screenshot: the process (nothing $\to$ ghost + nonghost) is energetically favoured, so the universe would near-instantly get filled by particles. Since the ghost particles are tachyons, they would move faster than light. Note that issues occur when the particles are interacting: a theory of a single particle species that doesn't interact is perfectly sensible in any case--apart from the fact that non-interacting particles cannot, even in principle, be observed.

Comment: What you say is interesting but I don't understand completely. How could the universe get filled with particles? The tachyons won't annihilate with ordinary particles? Moreover, couldn't we observe them by the fact that they would make disappear other particles that we would place on their way? And third question - I apologize for insistence - how big these tachyons might be?

Comment: Sorry, none of these questions make sense. A ghost, tachyon, or ghost-tachyon is not an antiparticle